# adjoint matrix of an operator

Tags: matrices, derivatives, adjoint-operators

considering a $2\times 2$ matrix $\bf S$,

\begin{equation}
   {\bf S} =  \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial}{\partial{t}} &  \kappa\nabla .\\ 1/\rho \nabla . &  \frac{\partial}{\partial{t}}  
  \end{bmatrix} 
  \end{equation}

I want to get the adjoint of $\bf S$, $$\bf S^{*}$$ for that I am using cofactor matrix and then I transpose this matrix (METHOD 1 to get adjoint matrix).

\begin{equation}
   {\bf S}_{\text{cof}} =  \begin{bmatrix} a_{11} &  a_{12} \\ a_{21} &  a_{22}  
  \end{bmatrix} 
  \end{equation}
as $$a_{ij}=(-1)^{i+j}\det\bf S_{ij}$$

\begin{eqnarray}
a_{11}&=&\frac{\partial}{\partial{t}}\\
a_{12}&=&-1/\rho \nabla .\\
a_{21}&=&-\kappa\nabla . \\
a_{22}&=&\frac{\partial}{\partial{t}}
\end{eqnarray}

In matrix notation we have,

\begin{equation}
   {\bf S}_{\text{cof}} =  \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial}{\partial{t}} &  -1/\rho \nabla \\ -\kappa\nabla . &  \frac{\partial}{\partial{t}}  
  \end{bmatrix} 
  \end{equation}

Transposing the matrix $$\bf S_{\text{cof}}$$ we get:

\begin{equation}
 {\bf S}^{*}=  \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial}{\partial{t}} &  -\kappa\nabla .   \\ -1/\rho \nabla .&  \frac{\partial}{\partial{t}}  
  \end{bmatrix} 
  \end{equation}

This is the way I am doing but I saw some other papers doing something different, the procedure other people are doing is transposing $\bf S$ and change the signal of every first derivative (METHOD 2 to get adjoint matrix), in this sense the adjoint of $\bf S$ is:

\begin{equation}
   {\bf S}^{*} =  \begin{bmatrix} - \frac{\partial}{\partial{t}} &  -1/\rho \nabla \\ -\kappa\nabla . & - \frac{\partial}{\partial{t}}  
  \end{bmatrix} 
  \end{equation}

Which method is right? Am I doing something wrong? If you have any documentation please share it.

Thank you,
Rafael